# Most elegant way to retry request on Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, retry-logic

I'm building my own ES Client in Java based on ElasticSearch's [`RestHighLevelClient`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java):

```
public class MyElasticSearchClient {
    private final RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

    @Inject
    public MyElasticSearchClient(RestHighLevelClient restHighlevelClient) {
        this.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
    }

    public MyEntryClass get(@NonNull final String searchId) { 
        ... 
        restHighLevelClient.get(new GetRequest('index-name', 'index-type', searchId);
        ...
    }

    public DocWriteResponse.Result update(@NonNull final MyEntryClass entry) { ... };

    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, `RestHighLevelClient` doesn't have a retry strategy like the [Python version](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/transport.py#L87-L88), which I would like to implement.

Without spamming try/catch on every request API that I define, are there any elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: its much needed, wonder if its there in python then why not in java, you can also raise a bug in their github repo https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues